# Error New-Item en powershell

Tags: powershell

Estoy creando un script con powershell en el que se debe crear un archivo .txt para los logos. Uso la siguiente sentencia:

```
New-Item -path "c:\users\user\desktop\log\logs.txt" -itemtype File
```

Y me arroja un error el cual dice que no se puede encontrar el archivo, al crearlo.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Quieres crear un archivo desde Powershell o quieres crear un archivo bash que genere el archivo?

Comment: Quiero, desde un script en powershell, crear un archivo .txt (o del tipo que sea, pero en este caso, txt)

Comment: Tal vez la siguiente respuesta te resulte útil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Escribe el mensaje de error exacto que te arroja el script. Es posible que la ruta donde piensas crear el archivo no exista?

Comment: Y está cierto que la folleta \users\user\desktop\log existe?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas resolverlo con lo siguiente:

```
type NUL > 1.txt
```

Otra manera

```
cd. > filename
```

Una forma más

```
copy nul file.txt > nul
```

Comment: Podría intentarlo, pero ya que estoy en powershell, me gustaría aprovechar el propio lenguaje para esto. Por eso, si alguien puede explicarme por qué me da ese error...

Answer (score 0):

El sintaxis del cmdLet esta bien según su documentación [New-item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6)

Comprobando su funcionamiento tal cual lo hiciste vos, me funciona perfecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única manera en que me da error es cuando el archivo ya existe realmente. Por lo que pienso que en otra parte de tu código tenes el error, o es posible que el archivo ya exista realmente, podrías probar cambiando el nombre y la ruta de acceso.

También deberías asegurarte estar ejecutando powershell como administrador, o tener los correctos permisos en las rutas que estas usando.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante recalcar que en el caso de que **no existan** las rutas intermedias, si no se especifica el parámetro `-Force`, el comando devolverá un error. En los siguientes enlaces se puede ampliar más esta información:

> El parámetro Force permite crear un archivo en la ruta de acceso del perfil, **incluso cuando los directorios de la ruta de acceso no existen**. [New-Item (Microsoft Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1#ejemplo-8-usar-el-par-metro-force-para-intentar-volver-a-crear-carpetas)

> [...] Create a file when the directories in the path do not
> exist (PowerShell will create them) [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20file%20when%20the%20directories%20in%20the%20path%20do%20not%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20exist%20(PowerShell%20will%20create%20them))

Una breve demostración:

Sin especificar el parámetro `-Force` a la hora de intentar crear el fichero "archivoDePrueba.txt" dentro de la carpeta "Prueba" la cual **no existe** (solo hay 3 directorios que comiencen por la letra "P" y ninguno es "Prueba"), devuelve un error de tipo *DirectoryNotFoundException*:
[image: Directorio de carpetas]

[image: Detalles de la excepción]
En cambio, cuando se le añade el parámetro, crea las rutas intermedias hasta llegar a la indicada:

[image: Uso del parámetro -Force]